# how to talk to local databases?

Tags: c#, database

I just added a new "local database" in my project using visual studio. Now I added the "New Data Source".

What I want to know is how you can do sql queries to the DB. I know how this is done in PHP but cant find good information about how to do this in C#. All I find is tutorials on how to drag detail or gridviews into the form.

I have one database called 'words' with three tables. I want to be able to do update queries to a row in each of these tables. something like this:

```
UPDATE easy SET words='blahblahblah' WHERE id=1;
```

How do you do this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio? Do you know _anything_ about data access with .NET?

Comment: Which DataBase is it? Most of the RDBMS have their own libraries except few supplied with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to use SQL Server as example.

First you need to find out the connection string which should be similar to

```
_connectionString = "Data Source=(localdb)\\v11.0; Initial Catalog=words;Integrated Security=true;"
```

and then you do

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE easy SET words='blahblahblah' WHERE id=1;", connection))
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```